# How to run KDM or GDM over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, xorg, x-windows

I have a computer on LAN running ssh. I can normally tunnel the GUI application using

```
ssh computer-name -X program-name
```

But I wam my full desktop to be running on a remote computer using ssh so that I can just use that computer remotely like a local desktop. For this I think I will need to run KDM (or GDM ) remotely, what configuration do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: this question is very similar to others that have been asked; do the answers to http://superuser.com/questions/118985/remote-desktop-logon-on-linux-from-windows-vista or http://superuser.com/questions/121809/remote-desktop-into-a-linux-machine-is-this-possible answer your question?

Comment: also see http://superuser.com/questions/70578/when-you-use-x-forwarding-to-run-an-application-on-another-computer-which-proces in regards to what your *ssh* command is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [howto](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO.html) for configuring XDMCP.

Or you can use something like [OpenVNC](http://openvncpro.sourceforge.net/) or [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For accessing a full Linux desktop remotely, I'd suggest you take a look at [NoMachine NX](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php). You need a server program running on the remote machine, and then use a client to log in remotely, after which a new Gnome or KDE session is launched and it's almost exactly like using the machine locally.

Disclaimer: I haven't used NoMachine NX recently or followed its development. However, a few years ago I was totally impressed by its speed and smoothness. Running graphical X programs over network is often really slow, but with this tool it was much more tolerable. (I e.g. used it to access my work computer at a uni seminar presentation for a hands-on IntelliJ IDEA coding example.)

Comment: Alternatively, look at FreeNX (http://freenx.berlios.de/) for a free-as-in-GPL NX server.